# Using R! How can I only bold some of the words in a column of a flextable and output it to .docx?

Tags: r, docx, officer

I'm a new 'officer' package user. I'm currently working on a project, which ask me to output a table to .docx. In that table, there is a field called 'Description' which contains some long texts. For example: "This is a description."
Now, I have a list of key words. For example, "description" is a key word in the list.
I want to bold any keyword in the Description field. How can I do that?

I have already print the table to a .docx file by using "flextable". And I'm able to set the bold output for a whole cell. But not able to only bold part of the cell content.
Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack overflow! Please provide a [minimal example of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that someone can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You have to create a paragraph which could contain multiple chunks with different styles. See https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content.html#multi-content